# DotNetNuke module javascript interferring with edit buttons

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I've been working on a DotNetNuke (DNN) site for a client and I believe I added some JS inside a module that may be interfering with the rest of the page's JS now.

They edit buttons for the modules on this page are no longer loading, so I'm curious to know if there is possibly a way to edit a module's HTML content without clicking on the edit button (which is not appearing anywhere in the DOM). Perhaps in the backend that I cannot find.

Just a note; I do NOT have access to the file system, or database. So this has to be done through the CMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by enabling the "Replace Tokens" option in the module settings.

I was then able to edit the HTML content and then disable Replace Tokens.

Comment: It was 'map is undefined' the previous developer had called it something different. The error was causing it to make the edit buttons not load.